# Draw circle to the screen

Tags: java, swing, graphics

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Drag extends JFrame {

    Drag(){     
        setSize(500,400);
        setTitle("Drag");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(0,0,30,30);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Drag frame1 = new Drag();
       }
}
```

I don't know where did i get wrong, but it just didn't create a circle to the screen for some reason

Comment: My guess is that `(0, 0)` is outside the frame. I would try something like `g.fillOval(20,20,30,30);`

Comment: Don't override `paint` of a top-level container. Instead, create a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.

Answer (score 0):

The JFrame coordinates begin at the top left corner of the window created with the y axis going down. To see your circle at the center of this window try 
`g.fillOval(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2,30,30);`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but by any chance is it because you're instantiating a JFrame outside of the event dispatch thread?

I can't test because I'm on my phone but if you want to you can try replacing mains code with this :

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
        new Drag ()
   }
});
```